# Loading a meta table as object

Tags: node.js, bookshelf.js

I have a table in my database called `users`. In this table I only store user ID, username and password. Now, in another table called `user_meta`, I have the following columns: `id, uid, meta_key, meta_value`. I'm trying to find a way for Bookshelf to automatically load all records in `user_meta` where `uid == userid`, and store them as `model.meta[meta_key] = meta_value`. Sadly, I haven't been able to find a way to make this possible.

If it is possible at all, the 2nd step would be to also save all values in `model.meta` back on update / insert, inserting records where `meta_key` doesn't exist for that user ID yet, and updating where it does.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the associations (relations) between the models:

```
var User = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'users',
  meta: function() {
    return this.hasMany(Meta);
  }
});

var Meta = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'user_meta',
  user: function() {
    return this.belongsTo(User);
  }
});
```

http://bookshelfjs.org/#one-to-many

Comment: Won't this give me an array of objects like `meta = [{meta_key: "key1", meta_value: "value1"}, ...]`? If so, that is not what I want. I want it to load as `meta['key1'] = "value1"`